# Persist an amount of messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I know that you can use retention to persist an amount of messages into disk by time or by size (in bytes).

Is it possible to do the same by amount of messages, instead by amount of bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not—only time or size : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#topicconfigs